# why am i recieving a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am in the process of trying to transpose a square two dimensional array, and have only been working with arrays a short while. I understand i am requesting an index that does exist for my array a. But how is this possible ? If i go through an iteration it seems to me there should be no problem.

my program consist of the two following classes.

```
public class Transposition {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matrix.transpose(new int[][] {new int[] {1, 2}, new int[] {3, 4}, new int[] {5, 6}, new int[] {7, 8}});
    }
}

public class Matrix {

    public static void transpose(int[][]a) {

        int n = a.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
                int temp = a[i][j];
                a[i][j] = a[j][i];
                a[j][i] = temp;                 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone would maybe give me some pointers.

Comment: "I am in the process of trying to transpose a square two dimensional array" - well, you don't *have* a square two dimensional array.

Comment: `for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)` this should be `for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {`. `i+1` causes exceeding the array when i reaches to the end.

Comment: @Rp- That won't help, `n` is `4` but the subarrays only have two entries.

Comment: Yes, thats correct, I thought it was 2x2.

Comment: Wowzers someone even formatted my question after posting. Also the amount of response to such a rudimentary question. I'ts quite the community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n` is the length of your outermost array. It's longer than the arrays that make up its elements. So looping while `j` is `< n` will cause the error, as `j` will exceed the length of the subordinate array.

> I am in the process of trying to transpose a square two dimensional array

As user2357112 [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828129/why-am-i-recieving-a-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-error/25828153#comment40406440_25828129), you don't have a square array. You have an array of 4x2 (an array of four entries, each of which consists of arrays of two entries).

Comment: The answer was right under my nose! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In your example your `int[][] a = new int[4][2]` so inside your method `n = 4` so  here:

`a[i][j] = a[j][i];` , `i` gets the values `0,1,2,3` but the sub-array length is `2` which means it has indices `0` and `1`. There you got your index out of bounds.